# How to search: %, %1$s, %3$d, %d

Tags: regex

Let me try to explain again.
I am trying to find these: %, %1$s, %3$d, %d from the following strings:

Number and % of Entries by Status
Value (in %s)
Last updated on %1$s at %2$s
Deletion failed since %d user(s) are

I tried to search with: %.*?[sd]
But I failed to exclude the brackets and it will include text that ends with an "s" for example the first line it will find "% of Entries".

Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so in order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all strings you are trying to target, and strings you are trying to exclude. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far. For further information, please refer to the [**help article**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions, and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`(%[sd\d$]*)`

Comment: Works! Thank you! :)